# Word 2007 - Macro to clean text

Tags: vba, text, ms-word

I am trying to write a macro that will format text.

This is what the original data looks like:

```
  This is sentence one of paragraph one. This is 
     sentence two of paragraph one. This is 
    sentence three of paragraph one. This is sentence 
    four of paragraph one. This is sentence five of 
    paragraph one.

  This is sentence one of paragraph two. This is 
    sentence two of paragraph two. This is 
      sentence three of paragraph two. This is sentence 
      four of paragraph two. This is sentence five of 
   paragraph two.
```

This is what I want the text to look like:

```
This is sentence one of paragraph one. This is sentence two of paragraph one. This is  
sentence three of paragraph one. This is sentence four of paragraph one. This is 
sentence five of paragraph one.

This is sentence one of paragraph two. This is sentence two of paragraph two. This is  
sentence three of paragraph two. This is sentence four of paragraph two. This is 
sentence five of paragraph two.
```

This macro would make sure that the text fills up the whole page and there is only one space between every word.  It needs to retain the paragraph structure.

I am calling this macro from Excel and running the readability statistics from Word.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub Test_Button1()

    Dim file As String
    Dim StatText As String
    Dim rs As Variant
    Dim row_count As Integer
    Dim header_count As Integer

    row_count = 0
    header_count = 0

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B5").Select

    Set appWD = New Word.Application
    appWD.Visible = True

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        row_count = row_count + 1
        OpenClipboard (0&)
        EmptyClipboard
        CloseClipboard
        ActiveCell.Copy
        appWD.Documents.Add
        appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        appWD.ActiveDocument.Select
        With appWD.Selection.ParagraphFormat
            .SpaceBefore = 0
            .SpaceAfter = 0
            .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
            .WidowControl = False
            .KeepWithNext = False
            .KeepTogether = False
            .PageBreakBefore = False
        End With

        If row_count = 1 Then
           ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
           For Each rs In appWD.ActiveDocument.readabilitystatistics
               header_count = header_count + 1
               ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
               ActiveCell.Value = rs.Name
           Next rs
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, -header_count).Select
        End If

        For Each rs In appWD.ActiveDocument.readabilitystatistics
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = rs.Value
            StatText = StatText & rs.Name & " - " & rs.Value & vbCr
        Next rs

        appWD.ActiveDocument.Select
        appWD.Selection.Delete
        appWD.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -header_count).Select
    Loop

    appWD.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges    
    Set appWD = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have already? In what way is it not working for you? It's hard to help you solve a problem if you don't tell us what that problem is in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Run a search-and-replace replacing dual newlines with a random string like "0PbEGMySxe3Bz4NOXUcw" that doesn't occur anywhere else in the document.
2. Run a search-and-replace replacing all remaining newlines with nothing
3. Replace multiple whitespace with one whitespace (repeat as needed).
4. Replace the random string from step 1 with paragraphs/newlines as needed.

If you don't want to look up how to do a search-and-replace programatically, you can record these actions with the built-in macro recorder, then adapt the code to fit your program.

The result is:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Makro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\n\n"
        .Replacement.Text = "asdfasdfasdf"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\n"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "asdfasdfasdf"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

You obviously want to clean that up before using it, and repeat the whitespace search-and-replace until nothing remains (e.g. just run it 10 times, it's exponential, that will be enough).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litte bit more?  I am kind of confused as to what you mean.

Comment: You can record macros, i.e. save the actions you do by clicking to a VBS function. Don't ask me where MS decided to hide that in Word 2007... anyways, I'll add the result to the answer now.

Comment: (+1) for a clean and simple solution - although you can remove lots of lines from this code since most of the optional parameters will default to the "sensible" (in this case) option.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this. This is the raw output from the macro recorder, to show how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Sub CleanWordDocument()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application, objDoc As Word.Document, c As Word.Range

    Set objWord = New Word.Application
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\test1.docx")

    Set c = objWord.ActiveDocument.Content
    c.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify

    With c.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        While .Found
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Wend
    End With

    objDoc.Save
    objWord.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub Macro1()

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p "
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Do While Selection.Find.Found
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute

Loop
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "  "
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Do While Selection.Find.Found
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute

Loop
```

End Sub